# Validate exception in web api controller save change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I got exception when trying to save changes using EF6 in WebApi controller. Exception is the follow:

```
Failed to authenticate with one or more entities. For more information, see the property "EntityValidationErrors".
```

From stack trace i found the follow:

```
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   в System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   в GuideOnline_1_.Controllers.xTouristController.PutxTourist(Int32 id, xTourist xtourist) в c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GuideOnline(1)\GuideOnline(1)\Controllers\xTouristController.cs:строка 55
   в lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Here is my controller (generated by VS automatically). And yes, I used to use DB first approach for generate model.

```
// PUT api/xTourist/5
        public IHttpActionResult PutxTourist(int id, xTourist xtourist)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != xtourist.Kod)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(xtourist).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!xTouristExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

I'm new to WebApi and Entity Framework, so I expect for advise from my experienced colleagues. Thanks in advance.
P.S.
I'm sure that everything is fine about jQuery code that passing values to xtourist object and controller to be saved as well as about sql part as it work fine when I'm running pure sql script.

P.P.S. I hope this is what you're looking for, Kirill.

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException не обработано пользовательским кодом
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Сбой при проверке одной или нескольких сущностей. Более подробные сведения см. в свойстве "EntityValidationErrors".
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       в System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       в System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
       в GuideOnline_1_.Controllers.xTouristController.PutxTourist(Int32 id, xTourist xtourist) в c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GuideOnline(1)\GuideOnline(1)\Controllers\xTouristController.cs:строка 55
       в lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       в System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

**UPDATE.** 
Final solution is:

```
try
            {
                var arrivals = db.xTourist.Find(id);
                arrivals.Номер = item.Номер;
                arrivals.Telefon = item.Telefon;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: what is message of your exception?

Comment: Failed to authenticate with one or more entities. For more information, see the property "EntityValidationErrors". Actually these exception details that I post before, I found it in stacktrace info.

Comment: and what is in EntityValidationErrors?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Short message was: Сбой при проверке одной или нескольких сущностей. Более подробные сведения см. в свойстве "EntityValidationErrors".

Comment: This input field is too short. Full message from StackTrace you can see above. Unless you mean something else.

Comment: `EntityValidationErrors` is a property attached to the exception. @KirillBestemyanov is asking what the contents of that property is.

Comment: Well, seemed I found what is problem. There is NOT NULL field. To say honestly I don't understand what is wrong, because problem with NOT NULL filed can be on INSERT but not on UPDATE.

Comment: If you set state modified to whole entry, it will update all columns. So problem with not null can be actual

Comment: Kirill, could you advise please how should I change the code to be able update only columns with modified data?

Comment: Now it's like that: db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                var arrivals = db.xTourist.Find(id);
                arrivals.AreaID = item.AreaID;.... db.saveChanges();